# Why does reading less than the given buffer size cause a security risk

Tags: c, security

Basically I'm presented with a question as follows:

(paraphrased)
What is the security vulnerability in this "code" assuming the functions are written in pseudo C

```
function (input) {
...
   len = get_int_from_network();
   buffer = malloc (len+7);
   read (input, buffer, len);
...
}
```

So I really want to understand why this is such a big deal. And yes this is not real C code I'm not declaring any variables or any other stuff, but the main thing that's important is shown. A buffer is being malloc'd with len + 7 bytes and reading only len bytes.

The part I'm confused about is that it shouldn't read more than it is supposed to and should only result in free space at the end of the buffer. I really can't think of anything that could go wrong and I've looked through my notes and we haven't talked about anything except integer overflows, buffer overflows, and string formatting errors. So I'm thoroughly perplexed. If you provide a detailed explanation you're my hero because I really want to learn *why* this is such a bad thing.

Comment: Are there any additional hints given? Are you sure it is about the length mismatch? I see some other points here: 1. `len` isn't valid, so check this before proceeding. 2. `buffer` is null, so check this before proceeding. 3. You are not sure `read()` reads everything, so check its return value indicating the length.

Comment: The other 7 bytes could contain information from another context, and the buffer then passed to another process. `malloc` does not clear the memory.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks! this is literally all that was given with the assumption that everything was declared beforehand. So what you said helps. The issue I was having was the last func call was read() and I don't have any context for how it is used. But seriously if that's the main issue then I don't feel as bad about missing it (thought it was something to do with the given code itself not how it will be used later)

Comment: @WeatherVane If you post it as an answer I will check as answer since it answered my question.

Comment: Consider what the types of the variables are, or may be, and what possible values they might hold.   For example, what happens if `len` is of type `int`, and the integer obtained from the network is negative?

Comment: @Peter: I think you've hit it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no security risk.

Well, no increased security risk, anyway.

The assumption that there is a security risk seems based on the belief that if you call `malloc( len )`, you can't access the memory returned past `len` bytes.

That's wrong.

And there's no other way to put it - **that's wrong**.

It's quite possible to read and write past the end of memory allocated by `malloc()`.  It's undefined behavior, but it is still quite possible.  If reading past the end of a buffer is a security risk, it's a security risk even if the buffer size is artificially enlarged to remove the undefined behavior.  Nor is any security risk removed by using a smaller buffer.

Because the memory is just about always still going to be there either way.

Second, almost every `malloc()` implementation doles out memory in chunks of discrete sizes.  That's done to satisfy the requirement that `malloc()` return memory ["suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated"](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3).  That means `malloc()` must return memory that starts on something like an 8- or 16-byte (maybe even larger) boundary - or something similar. There's also internal accounting done, again causing memory blocking into chunks.  See [glibc's `malloc()` for example](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/malloc/malloc.c.html#1058).  Memory can also be chunked to help prevent fragmentation.

What that means is if you call `malloc( sizeof( int ) )` to ask for a 4-byte chunk of memory, you **really** get, for example, a 16-byte chunk.

So what happens when you call `malloc( sizeof( int ) + 7 )`?

Right - you actually get the same 16-byte chunk.

So why is allocating a buffer larger than you need a security risk?

In the real world it's not.

You can also look at it this way:  if allocating a larger buffer than needed is a security risk, not allocating that larger buffer relies on undefined behavior to always act in way to remove that security risk.

**Bottom Line**

Anyone who claims `malloc( sizeof( int ) )` is safe but `malloc( sizeof( int ) + 7 )` is a security risk **is implicitly assuming undefined behavior can be relied upon to remove security risks**.

That's, umm, unsound.

**Actual risk**

The actual security risk in the code - if any - is as @Peter noted.  The apparent risk is assuming the value returned from `get_int_from_network()` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks why this is a **security** risk.

The library function `malloc` does not clear the memory, and so the buffer might contain information from another context. If the buffer is then passed to another process, it could examine its contents to see what other data can be harvested.

If you really need the spare bytes available, the buffer can be allocated with `calloc` which zeroes the memory.

Also you should make sure all the data available was read. The function `read` returns the number of bytes read, and should be called in a loop until they have all been received.